# Intro.js is opensource or not?

Tags: intro.js

I started to using the useful [Intro.js](https://introjs.com/) library in my project, but after few months use I updated it and found that the license changed on 08/03/2016.

The library is definitely open source and free software, but at the same time if I want use it for commercial use it seems I [need to pay a license fee](https://introjs.com/#commercial). Why is this required if the code is open source?

Maybe I'm missing something because I'm new in the license use world.

Answer (score 3):

I'm Afshin, the author of Intro.js

Intro.js is open-source and it will be free to use for everyone. I recently added a commercial license to the project to provide a better support, versions, etc. So, if you are using the project in a commercial app/theme/plugin you need to have a commercial license.

I suggest reading this as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_models_for_open-source_software

Comment: Hi thanks for reply and for give us this useful library.
I read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License that license that you choose is very near and compatible with GPL so i don't undestand why i need to have a license for that?

Comment: Maybe is better make a second version, with few additional feature, and license these with a commerial license.
Theorically I able to fork you project and make my "FreeIntro.js" and release it without any commercial issues.

Comment: It reads "Intro.js is a free and open-source library, however, if you are using the library for your business you can subscribe to one of commercial licenses plus support, code review and support by Intro.js team." Since it reads "can." To me that means it's optional. Please change this word to "must" or "need" if it is required.

Comment: It should be "if you are using the library for your business you must/should subscribe to ...."

Comment: "Intro.js is open-source and it will be free to use for everyone." and "if you are using the project in a commercial app/theme/plugin you need to have a commercial license." contradict each other...

Answer (score 1):

From their website:

> Intro.js is a free and open-source library, however, **if you are using
>   the library for your business you can subscribe to one of commercial
>   licenses plus support**, code review and support by Intro.js team.

Being open-source doesn't mean that everything has to be free, open-source software can be sold and used in general commercially. Also, commercial open-source applications are a part of the software industry for some time.

You can read all the information about selling open source software right [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_models_for_open-source_software).

Comment: Yes but in license.md in github they write:
"If you want to use Intro.js for a commercial application, theme or plugin the commercial license is the appropriate license. "
So I'm confused, also for my bad english,  if I can use this software for commercial purpose without pay any license. I can or not?

Comment: Its easy, if you are using `Intro.js` for making something that you are going to sell or gain money with (commercial application), yes, you have to pay for a commercial license.